# EXCEL 2010: Using INDEX with IF (possibly Nested)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program**  Excel 2010
**Experience**  Basic

Hi there,
I am wanting to define results in a cell using `INDEX` and `IF`.  I have managed to work the information out using `VLOOKUP`, however I am converting my VLs over to `INDEX/MATCH`.

I have tried a number of ways of writing this.  I can call the 1st result, always, but never the "else/part 2" it just keeps erroring.

```
=IF(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="MSN: ",INDEX(cMSN,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)),(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="Skype:",INDEX(cskype,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))))
```

This results in an error "The formula you typed contains an error".
The result should be:  If PrefContact = MSN, then Skype name.  If PrefContact = SKYPE, then Skype address.  If there are neither Skype nor MSN pref, then "".

The working VLOOKUP:

```
'=IF(VLOOKUP($A$6,Contractors,18)="Skype:",VLOOKUP($A$6,Contractors,18) & " " & VLOOKUP($A$6,Contractors,20),IF(VLOOKUP($A$6,Contractors,18)="MSN: ",VLOOKUP($A$6,Contractors,18) & " " & VLOOKUP($A$6,Contractors,20),""))
```

I've used the `&` to concat 2 cells (MSN: address)  (Skype: address) rather than 2 columns, I only need 1.

I'd like to do the same using the INDEX/MATCH function however I can't get past the 1st problem and that is using it in an `IF`

I know, if it works in one, why bother with the other?  Well, there is much debate on `INDEX/MATCH` vs `VLOOKUP` and I want my book to run smoother, it's going to be a large Invoice/Sales history.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I see you've missed `If` before `(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="Skype:"`. So formula should be: `=IF(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="MSN: ",INDEX(cMSN,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)),IF(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="Skype:",INDEX(cskype,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))))`

Comment: Thank you @simoco I still get an error though and my mouse highlights the 2nd `"` in "skype**"**.

Comment: something wrong with `"` quote sign. Try to delete it and write again  in excel (for me it fixes the issue).

Comment: @simoco that worked, all `""` are now correct.  I also amended the end of the string to `)),""))` so now if there are no MSN or Skype then it returns a blank cell.  Please submit as your answer and I can accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this formula works:

```
=IF(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="MSN: ",
      INDEX(cMSN,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)),
         IF(INDEX(PrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="Skype:"‌​,
            INDEX(cskype,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)),""))
```

Comment: thank you, the full `INDEX` I can now use is:  `=IF(INDEX(cPrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="MSN: ",INDEX(cPrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)) & " " & INDEX(cMSN,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)),IF(INDEX(cPrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0))="Skype:",INDEX(cPrefContact,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)) & " "& INDEX(cskype,MATCH(A6,ManID,0)),""))`  Works perfectly!